# Calling a Draw function in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, graphics

I have the following code in my Draw2D class which is attached to the view in the viewcontroller.

In the viewcontroller I have a var `Drawing = Draw2D()`. I have a button hooked up which performs the function "Check" with `self.Drawing.Check()`. The problem is I can't get the line on the screen. The ellipse works fine and function Check performs well as I can see with `println()`.
What is wrong?

```
import UIKit

class Draw2D: UIView {

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 4.0)
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.blueColor().CGColor)
        let rectangle = CGRectMake(60,170,200,80)
        CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rectangle)
        CGContextStrokePath(context)
    }

    func Check() {
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0)
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, CGFloat(100), CGFloat(300))
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, CGFloat(100 + 200), CGFloat(300 + 100))
        CGContextStrokePath(context)
    }
}
```

Comment: where is `Check()` called?

Comment: This is the viewcontroller

Comment: 'var Drawing = Draw2D()

    @IBAction func Button1(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        self.Drawing.Check()
    }'

Comment: Drawing is done in `drawRect` which is call by the system. You need to change the `drawRect` to handle drawing the check.

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `Check()` is outside of the regular rendering loop - I do not really know what `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` actually returns in that case. I am guessing it will return `nil`:

> The current graphics context is nil by default. Prior to calling its drawRect: method, view objects push a valid context onto the stack, making it current.

Anyway that would not change the fact that you cannot just call `Check()` and expect the line to be rendered. Assume for a second that the line was actually rendered: in the next rendering iteration you again only will do what is written inside `drawRect` and will therefore not display the line again.

What you have to do is create some kind of logic inside the `drawRect` to determine wether to call `Check()` or not.

A possible way to do this would be the following:

```
class Draw2D: UIView {

    var callCheck:Bool? // changing it to Bool! or Bool will change the required check a few lines below

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 4.0)
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.blueColor().CGColor)
        let rectangle = CGRectMake(60,170,200,80)
        CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rectangle)
        CGContextStrokePath(context)
        if callCheck != nil && callCheck! {
            Check()
        }
    }

    func Check() {
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0)
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, CGFloat(100), CGFloat(300))
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, CGFloat(100 + 200), CGFloat(300 + 100))
        CGContextStrokePath(context)
    }
}
```

Alter your `IBAction`:

```
@IBAction func Button1(sender: AnyObject) { 
    self.Drawing.callCheck = true
    self.Drawing.setNeedsDisplay() 
}
```

Comment: Hi and thx thusfar. What I really would like to do is a setup described in drawRect and then a func drawLine which draws all the lines and can be called form every other function. Where and how would I declare that drawLine function?

Comment: And BTW, I can't get the suggested alterations to work

Comment: You can declare it wherever you want, you just have to move the logic when to call that drawLine method to `drawRect`. EVERYTHING that draws anything must be invoked directly or indirectly from `drawRect`

Comment: I have put the drawLine function in drawRect before, however with the same negative result.

Comment: @user2761551 have you made sure that your coordinates are actually on screen, the code actually gets executed and you have set a correct color?

Comment: Yes, I have checked it with println and I always get this error: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

Comment: @user2761551 what happens if you just move all the content from Check() inside the drawRect()?

Comment: To be more specific: in all the examples regarding drawing and using graphics, everything is put up in a single func drawRect. I can't find any examples of calling other functions which draw as well on the screen.

Comment: Can anyone of you program a function drawRect which draws something on the screen and then calling other functions (inside the main class), no matter what, which draw as well on the screen?